# ubuntu software center does not open after tried to install spotify

Tags: spotify

i tried to install spotify on my computer (using Ubuntu since 1 week)
i dont know anything about ubuntu
and the installation failed

finally now the Ubuntu software center does not open

i tried that :

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center

and at the end of the list, i got that :

> SystemError: E:Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list

any idea to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your computer told you exactly how to fix it. `'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`

To fix it, open a terminal and run

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

And remove 'sudo' from the first line of the file.

Comment: As an added bonus, the software center should work after this too, since it won't get an error with the source list.